# Combine column output by comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

From the below result, I would like to combine `committees_attendees` based on `Work_WorkID` using colon separated:

```
select distinct 
    w.Work_WorkID, k.Name as "Committees_Attendees"  
from 
    DTree d, WMap m, WSubWork s, WWork w, WFAttrData a, KUAF k
where 
    d.DataID = m.Map_MapObjID 
    and m.Map_MapID = s.SubWork_MapID 
    and s.SubWork_WorkID = w.Work_WorkID
    and w.Work_WorkID = a.WF_ID 
    and d.DataID = 35269818 
    and a.WF_AttrID = 5 
    and k.ID = a.WF_ValInt
```

This is the result from above query:

```
Work_WorkID Committees_Attendees
--------------------------------
35273587    Deva
35273587    Eswar
```

And this is the expected output:

```
 Work_WorkID    Committees_Attendees
-------------------------------------
    35273587    Deva ; Eswar
```

I tried with XML path like below but couldn't get two column desired output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    e.results AS "Secretariat_Attendees" 
FROM
    (SELECT
         REPLACE(STUFF(CAST((SELECT ' ; ' + CAST(c.Secretariat_Attendees AS VARCHAR(MAX)), c.WorkID
                             FROM 
                                 (SELECT DISTINCT 
                                      w.Work_WorkID AS WorkID,
                                      k.Name AS Secretariat_Attendees  
                                  FROM 
                                      DTree d, WMap m, WSubWork s, WWork w, WFAttrData a, KUAF k
                                  WHERE 
                                      d.DataID = m.Map_MapObjID 
                                      AND m.Map_MapID = s.SubWork_MapID 
                                      AND s.SubWork_WorkID = w.Work_WorkID
                                      AND w.Work_WorkID = a.WF_ID 
                                      AND d.DataID = 35269818 
                                      AND a.WF_AttrID = 17  
                                      AND k.ID = a.WF_ValInt) c 
                             ORDER BY
                                 c.WorkID
                             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 1, 2, ''), ' ', '') AS results
     FROM
         wfattrdata t) e;
```

Result:

```
Secretariat_Attendees
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AdminCEOOffice<WorkID>35273587</WorkID>;Diana<WorkID>35273587</WorkID>
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's on how to `concat` your column.

```
select * into #res from (
    select '35273587' as Work_WorkID ,'Deva' Committees_Attendees
    union all
    select '35273587' ,'Eswar' 
)res


select distinct t2.Work_WorkID,
    stuff((select N' ; ' + Committees_Attendees
       from (select Work_WorkID, Committees_Attendees
          from #res t1 where t1.Work_WorkID = t2.Work_WorkID) AS t  
       for xml path('')
    ), 1, 2, '') + N''
from #res t2;
drop table #res
```

applying on your actual tables, its easier to use `cte`

```
with cte as (
select  Distinct w.Work_WorkID,k.Name as  "Committees_Attendees"  from DTree d,WMap m,WSubWork s,WWork w,WFAttrData a,KUAF k
    where d.DataID=m.Map_MapObjID and m.Map_MapID=s.SubWork_MapID and s.SubWork_WorkID=w.Work_WorkID
    and w.Work_WorkID=a.WF_ID and d.DataID=35269818 and a.WF_AttrID=5 and k.ID=a.WF_ValInt
)
select distinct t2.Work_WorkID,
    stuff((select N' ; ' + Committees_Attendees
       from (select Work_WorkID, Committees_Attendees
          from cte t1 where t1.Work_WorkID = t2.Work_WorkID) AS t  
       for xml path('')
    ), 1, 2, '') + N''
from cte t2;
```

Comment: you can use common table expression, see updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about Oracle SQL, you can use LISTAGG (List Aggregate). It's an aggregate function which does exactly that (convert columns to a character-separated string).

It has the expected limitation of maximum accepted values, though; so you might not be able to concatenate a thousand columns XD.

List Aggregate against your query:

```
SELECT "Work_WorkID", LISTAGG("Committees_Attendees", ' ; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Committees_Attendees") "Committees_Attendees" 
    FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT W.WORK_WORKID "Work_WorkID", K.NAME AS "Committees_Attendees" 
        FROM DTREE D, WMAP M, WSUBWORK S, WWORK W, WFATTRDATA A, KUAF K
            WHERE D.DATAID = M.MAP_MAPOBJID AND M.MAP_MAPID = S.SUBWORK_MAPID AND S.SUBWORK_WORKID = W.WORK_WORKID
            AND W.WORK_WORKID = A.WF_ID AND D.DATAID = 35269818 AND A.WF_ATTRID = 5 AND K.ID = A.WF_VALINT)
        -- GROUP BY "Work_WorkID"
```

If you need it for MySQL, you might want to look for GROUP_CONCAT.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: The OP is clearly asking about SQL Server, not Oracle or MySQL.